# How to solve $|\tan x| \ge 1$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need to solve  $$|\tan x| \ge 1$$
So I separated it to cases $$-{\sin x\over \cos x}\ge1$$ And $${\sin x\over \cos x}\ge1$$ But now I've got so many cases to check it seems like I'm doing it in the wrong way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, the easiest way to do this is to solve $\tan x = \pm1$, then draw the graph of $y = \tan x$ and the graph of $y=\pm 1$. After that I think it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: wouldn't it put me back at the start? i'll get that y=tanx needs not to be between y=1 and y=-1 so i'll still have to solve it in the regular 1000 cases way

Comment: Did you actually draw the picture? Also, note that $\tan x$ is periodic, so you don't need to work over every period to describe what's going on. There is a simple pattern.

Comment: Its hard to show it in paint but here http://s9.postimg.org/450tlv9kv/Untitl1ed.png so I get $y=\tan x$ needs to be bigger than $y=1$ hence $y=\tan x > y=1 > 1$ and vice versa for the $(-)$ so it didn't advance me to anywhere

Comment: Suppose $z$ is the value in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ for which $\tan z = 1$. Notice $\tan x > 1$ if $z < x < \pi/2$...if you can find $z$ then this is halfway toward your answer.

Comment: Oh ok thanks I got $\frac{\pi}{4}\le x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{- \pi}{2}<x \le \frac{- \pi}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Draw a graph of $\tan x$ to get a general idea.